# CRM Outlook Add-in: where to get the list of idMso values?

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm-2011, ms-office, dynamics-crm, outlook-addin

I need a list of idMso values to further customize the CRM ribbon on the standard mail and appointment Outlook windows.

Specifically I am interested in these controls:

"CRM" group
"Untrack" button
"Set Regarding" button

Here is the screenshot of the ribbon group I am talking about:

[image: screenshot]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Outlook >> Choose file >> Select customizeRibbon option. On the *right* pane just select Mail Tabs/ALL Tabs/Tool Tabs from dropdown and do hover over the control names. On hover the name you find is idMso value for that control button.

Comment: I don't have an opportunity to verify this, but thank you for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the standard ribbon `XML` definitions inside the CRM 2011 SDK, the folder is `resources\exportedribbonxml`.

By the way I suggest to use an editor for ribbon modifications, one is

[Ribbon Workbench for Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.develop1.net/public/page/Ribbon-Workbench-for-Dynamics-CRM-2011.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I have seen those. They seem to be in a different format though. For example there is no such element as "Groups" in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" namespace. As I mentioned in the question I want to change ribbons of Outlook windows not CRM windows.

Comment: If you want to change the ribbons displayed inside the CRM outlook client you need to modify the CRM Ribbons, look for example at this msdn article [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334209.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334209.aspx), you can see also the rules for the outlook client. You can also add a screenshot inside your question to explain better what you want to achieve

Comment: I want to modify the CRM group added to standard _Outlook_ ribbon, not one of the CRM ribbons. I have added a screenshot to demonstrate which one I mean. Thanks.